# Galton Watson tree with various kinds of offspring

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

As far as I understood, for the Galton-Watson tree process, the offspring are of one type. I am thinking of the case where we have offspring of different types. I have illustrated this in the example below: 
[image]

It can be seen that we have both sad face and happy face, rather than just a single type emoji. I am interested to find out the expected height of such trees for a given face (happy or sad). Let us assume that the reproduction goes with Poisson distribution.

I know that if we had only one type of children we could write the expectation via a generating function. First the generating function would be: 
$$f(s)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(Z_n=k)s^k$$
where $k$ is the number of children and $P(Z_n=k)$ the probability and $s$ is a dummy variable in that case we can define:
$$m=E[Z_n]=f'(s)|_{s=1}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(Z_n=k)k$$ 
I am not sure but I think for the two type (Happy and Sad) we should have something like: 
$$E[Z_0]=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P[n=k](1/2)\max _{i=1...k}(1+E[X_i])�$$
where $\max _{i=1...k}(1+E[X_i])$ is the maximum expectation for each child and factor of 1/2 appears as we assume 50-50 chance of being happy or sad. Are there such situations in literature?

---

**Update:** 
Since becoming familiar with multi type branching processes, I formatted my problem as follow:

I am considering a branching process with two types. I shall designate them with 1 and 2. The branching process follows Poisson distribution. So to that end I may write the probability generating functions as: 
$$f^1(\mathbf s)=\sum^{\infty}_{k_1=0}p_{k_1}s^{k_1}=e^{\lambda(s_1-1)}$$
$$f^2(\mathbf s)=\sum^{\infty}_{k_2=0}p_{k_2}s^{k_2}=e^{\lambda(s_2-1)}$$
I have borrowed this notation from the fact that, 
$$f^i({\mathbf s})=\sum_{\mathbf k}p_i(\mathbf k)s^{k_1}_{1}s^{k_2}_{2}\cdots s^{k_m}_{1}$$
Now I wonder how shall I proceed to calculate the extinction probability from here?

Comment: I think you need two generating functions $H$ and $S$ in two variables: $h$ and $s$. Try googling multi-type Galton Watson process.

Comment: This situation is definitely in the literature; these are typically called multi-type branching processes (rather than Galton-Watson processes).  You can see an overview [here](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2015/REUPapers/Csernica.pdf), or check out the book by Mode on multitype processes for more information.

Comment: Is it on purpose that sad faces only have sad children ? According to your description, it seems that it is not. If so, maybe you should arrange the picture.

Comment: I don't follow your update; it appears from what you wrote that each type can only have children of its own type (i.e. $f^i$ only depends on $s_i$).  Is this what you wanted?